# Multiple Ids of table A referring to Table B how to set relationship?

Tags: php, laravel-5, relationship

I have a teams table which has following structure :

```
id | manager_id | leader_id | member_id |
```

All of these three ids i.e manager_id leader_id and member_id are referring to id of employees table how do I set relationship because usually I do :

```
public function functionName()
{
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Employee', 'id', 'manager_id');
}
```

But not able to figure out in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Team` model methods

```
public function manager(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Employee', 'manager_id', 'id');
}

public function leader(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Employee', 'leader_id', 'id');
}

public function member(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Employee', 'member_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: this way I'll I have to call thrice like Team::with(['manager', 'leader', 'member']) and it will create three different objects there i nothing like I can do it in a single loading ?